# how do i go from pop up login of MainActivity to another activity

Tags: java, android

i am trying to login from custom dialog box which open from Button on MainActivity but when i click on login button of custom dialog box app get crashed with error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method main_login(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnLogin'"

**MainActivity.class**

```
package com.example.acetec;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name,email,password;
    String Name,Email,Password;
    Context ctx=this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);


        final Button mShowDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mShowDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.login,null);


                        mBuilder.setView(mView);
                        AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                        dialog.show();
```

**login.class**

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name,password;
    String Name, Password;
    Context ctx=this;
    String NAME=null, PASSWORD=null, EMAIL=null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);


    }
    public void main_login(View v){
        Name = name.getText().toString();
        Password = password.getText().toString();
        BackGround b = new BackGround();
        b.execute(Name, Password);
    }
```

i expect to go to new activity when i click login on custom dialog box of mainactivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a click listner to your AlertDialog like this

```
mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Start activity", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         //here you create your intent aand startActivity
    }
});

mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
```

Comment: sorry @Amine.....its still gives the same error with the following error code...java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method main_login(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnLogin'"